# OS X tool to convert MPEG-TS into MPEG-PS

Tags: encoding, vlc, video

I have a cable tv settop box capable of recording the MPEG-TS bit stream on to a USB-drive similar to what I can do with EyeTV on my Mac.

Unfortunately I have found that XBMC and VLC are the only OS X tools which can cope with these files, and I would like to have something simple which can convert this into a normal MPEG-PS file compatible with QuickTime for further processing.   I am well versed in Terminal.app, and can compile from source.

What should I use for this?

Answer (score 2):

You can probably compile your own ffmpeg then use:

```
ffmpeg -i input.ts -vcodec copy -acodec copy output.mpg
```

http://jungels.net/articles/ffmpeg-howto.html

Comment: Use [Homebrew](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew) to make installation even easier.